# Org footnote mark prevents end of sentence from being recognized

Tags: org-mode

I use a double spaces after full stops to seperate sentences, and
this is respected by `M-q`.  But with an org footnote mark after
the full stop, the sentence limit is not recognized, and the space
is reduced to a single after `M-q`.[1] Can I make emacs ignore the
footnote mark?

- Footnotes

[1] ...

Comment: I tend to deal with this by putting footnotes or citations before the . rather than after it, though tastes may vary.

Comment: @kini, doesn't that suggest that the note pertains only to the last word?

Comment: The relevant variable is `sentence-end-base`.  Modifying that so that a "." can optionally be followed by "[[:digit]]" should work.

Comment: @Toothrot I don't think so... footnotes can refer to the preceding word, phrase, clause, sentence, or even entire paragraph, depending on the context. Or at least that's how I read them.